# using redis to store time series / historical data

Tags: redis

I'm trying to implement the redis solution suggested here: http://www.slideshare.net/cacois/cois-palkostrata2013: it is the best I have found so far.

[image]

I have the following data structure "hash"

```
{'user': username, 'text': sometext, 'time': 1400543375}
```

I want to save the data in a log, the slides suggest saving it in a sorted list. When I try this:

```
zadd mysortedset 1400543375 {'user': username, 'text': sometext, 'time': 1400543375}
```

I get

```
Invalid argument(s)
```

so I thought I should create the hash first and then add it to the set

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET setmember:1400543375 user username text sometext time 1400543375
OK
```

and then

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd mysortedset 1400543375 setmember:1400543375
(integer) 1
```

Is this the way it is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What’s simply missing are the quotes around your JSON. Otherwithe it tries to interpret your zadd as scove value score value. And „username,“ is no valid score. ;) I tried it with

```
zadd mysortedset 1234 ”{’user’: foo …}”
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

A log suggest you get the entries in the right order to begin with. In which case use the l* commands (`lpush`,`lpop` etc)